# Issue with scraping data from websites

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to gather data by scraping webpages using Java with Jsoup. Ideally, I'd like about 8000 lines of data, but I was wondering what the etiquette is when it comes to accessing a site that many times. For each one, my code has to navigate to a different part of the site, so I would have to load 8000 (or more) webpages. Would it be a good idea to put delays between each request so I don't overload the website? They don't offer an API from what I can see.

Additionally, I tried running my code to just get 80 lines of data without any delay, and my internet is out. Could running that code have caused it? When I called the company, the automated message made it sound like service was out in the area, so maybe I just didn't notice it until I tried to run the code. Any help is appreciated, I'm very new to network coding. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, generally it is a good idea to have delays between each request. Also, check for the robot.txt of the website

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the robot.txt was so important, the one for the website in question just has: User-agent: * Allow: / for its robot.txt, so I think that means crawlers are allowed with no restrictions from what I've googled, but I'll still use a delay just in case.

Comment: Yes, just try to always be mindful of the website itself

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of things you should consider and things that I learned while writing a super-fast web **scraper** with Java and Jsoup:

1. Most important one is legal aspect, whether website allows crawling and till what extent they allow using their data.
2. Putting delays is fine but adding custom user agents that are compatible with robots.txt is more preferred. I had seen significant increase in response times with changing user agent from default to robots.txt.
3. If site allows and you need to crawl big number of pages, which was allowed for one of my previous project, you could use theadexecutor to load N number of pages simultaneously. It turns hours of data gathering job with single threaded java web **scraper** into just couple of minutes.
4. Many ISP's blacklist users who are doing programmable repeatative tasks such as web crawling and setting up email servers. Its varies from ISP to ISP. I previously avoided this by using proxies.

With a website having a response time of 500ms per request, my web **scraper** was able to **scrape** data from 200k pages with 50 threads, 1000 proxies in 3 minutes over a connection of 100MBPS.

**Should there be delays between requests?**

Answer: It depends if website allows you constantly hitting then you don't need it but should be better to have it. I had a delay of 10ms between each request.

**I tried running my code to just get 80 lines of data without any delay, and my internet is out?**

Answer: Most probably. ISP may assume you are doing DOS attack against the website and may have temporarily/permanently put a limit on your connection.